# Put a box outside the scrollable-menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dropdown menu scrollable with options. I also have on top of that a search-box (example "CAR"). Now the search-box makes part of the scrollable menu, so when you scroll down the search box goes away. I need the search box to stay fixed on top of the scrollable menu. So basically I have to move the search box "out" of the scrollable-menu section. The problem is in my javascript code (my html is fine, thats for sure) but I cannot find it, is it possible to achieve my goal?

My BOOTPLY... [BOOTPLY][1]

Answer (score 0):

Simply change your HTML like this:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu brand">
            <div style="position: relative;">
                <input class="Car" placeholder="Car" type="text">
                <div class=" scrollable-menu" style="margin-bottom: 70px;">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input value="" type="checkbox"> Alpha</label>
            </div>
```

I moved `<input class="Car" placeholder="Car" type="text">` above your scrollable-menu div, it was your HTML after all.

You should also change the variable targetinput like this:

```
var targetinput = currentgroup.find('.Car > input[type="text"]');
```

It should select your textbox propperly now, this is because you tried to find a textbox within the class scrolllable menu, however we moved the textbox outside of it.

Comment: sorry, its still not correct, somehow the functionality of the search-box is lost when i change my html, so it must be in the javascript somewhere.